# Can AWS Lambda coldout cause API Gateway timeout(30s)?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, cold-start

I am currently managing a website via Django.
The website's url will request an api which is stored in AWS Lambda Function.

Normally, a python based Lambda function with no VPC setting coldout wouldn't worry us.

But I have 2 concerns about my website performance.

1. The server function communicates with several 3rd party features like AWS S3, Firestore, Firebase Authentication, and DynamoDB. So every Lambda function needs to build up the required settings.
2. Every page of the website checks the Firebase authentication which persistance is local. Could process delay be critical to a coldstarted container, causing 30s timeout?

If some user occasionaly experience the API Gateway timeout, could the cause of this be AWS Lambda coldstart?

Answer (score 1):

No, the cold start will never be that high. For all cases, cold start should be less than 1 second (even for lambdas bound to VPC).